# How to add my own culture resources to tfs web access

Tags: tfs, localization, resources, culture, satellite-assembly

How can i add my own culture to Team Foundation Server web application, in order to use my language for web access UI?
(adding  my language to Language combobox in Profile Locale Settings.)

[image: my profile-->locale]

I tried to modify Deutsch Language by changing the resource files under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\de" folder with hex editor, but the new dll doesnt work.
 Also i create a new resource dll with Visual Studio and using the same resource names with different values, with same file version and .net version. but when i replace the resource dll (ex. Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.Welcome.resources.dll) the ui loads default language and ignores my new dll.
As shown in picture below it doesnt shows my new translated text, even it is not showing selected language(Deutsch) and its shows the default language(English).

 what am i missing?

[image: Editing Resource in Visual Studio]
[image: The Result in tfs Web Access]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well，it's not supported to customize the web portal home page in TFS projects now.

This can be achieved in *Visual Studio Team Services* if using the **extensions**. However for TFS, still waiting :) See for more information: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/extensions/overview

Also you can take a look at below from UserVoice

> **Customization of TFS Web Access**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3352200-customization-of-tfs-web-access